# how to add a field if not exists in mysql table

Tags: mysql

table orders

```
customers_id | name
1 | jimmy
```

I want to add a field 'refer_id' in table orders if it is not exists

```
customers_id | name | refer_id
1 | jimmy | 0
```

how to write if conditions?

```
alter table orders add refer_id int(11) default 0 if ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
delimiter '//'

CREATE PROCEDURE addcol() BEGIN

IF NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME='refer_id' AND TABLE_NAME='orders' 
    )
    THEN
        alter table orders add refer_id int(11) default 0 
END IF;
END;
//

delimiter ';'

CALL addcol();

DROP PROCEDURE addcol;
```

Comment: Please, [cite your sources](http://forums.codewalkers.com/database-help-83/alter-table-structure-conditional-adding-columns-if-they-dont-already-856291.html#post200392).

Answer (score 1):

why using if here ?

try this

```
   ALTER TABLE orders ADD refer_id int(11)  default 0  AFTER name;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not built it but it can be accomplished using the information_schema database

[see here](http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/mysql/howto_add_column_unless_exists.htm)